# Angular unit test not respecting click event

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I am writing a simple unit test for a element click '

Here is my html

```html
<div *ngIf="!hidden" id='button'>
    <button
        [color]="'primary'"
        [disabled]="disabled"
        [label]="lablel"
        id="createButton"
        (click)="handleNextClick()"
        id='button'
    ></button>
</div>
```

Here is my unit test

```js
it('should handleNextClick method called on button click', () => {
        let createsearchCreateDiv = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#button'));
        createsearchCreateDiv.nativeElement.click();



        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            expect(component.handleNextClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

    });
```

My test case is passed irrespective of below line

```
createsearchCreateDiv.nativeElement.click();
```

Ideally it should not pass only if I remove/comment above line.

Method is not getting called if I remove/comment click. But still test case getting passed

Answer (score 1):

It's an async call, so you should use `done`, `async/await` or return the `Promise`:

```
it('should handleNextClick method called on button click', () => {
  // ...
  return fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(component.handleNextClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```